# HTML not showing in directline website

Tags: c#, html, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I've written a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework in C# and have included the following html in it

```
        await context.PostAsync($"How would you like to connect, {username} ?");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<html><head>");
        sb.Append("<style>");
        sb.Append(".button{"); sb.Append("padding:10px25px;background-color:white;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;outline:none;color:#66b3ff;background-color:white;border-width:1px;border-color:#a6a6a6;border-radius:0px;}");
        sb.Append(".button:hover{"); sb.Append("border-color:#66b3ff;color:#66b3ff;background-color:white;}");
        sb.Append(".button:active{"); sb.Append("color:white;background-color:#66b3ff;border-color:#66b3ff;}");
        sb.Append("</style>");
        sb.Append("</head><body>");
        sb.Append("<a href=\"mailto:abc@abc.com?Subject=Place%20Subject%20here");
        sb.Append("\" target=\"_top\"><button class=\"button\">");
        sb.Append("Connect with Mail"); sb.Append("</button></a>");
        sb.Append("<a href=\"tel:+1111111111\"><button class=\"button\">");
        sb.Append("Connect with Call"); sb.Append("</button></a>");
        sb.Append("</body></html>");
        await context.PostAsync(sb.ToString());
```

When tested in the **bot emulator** it works fine. It looks like this

[image]

But then I deployed it using direct channel api. And it directly shows the html code instead of the buttons given above. When run on webpage this shows up

[image]

I'm sorry for a crappy photo. Is there a way of displaying html in the bot using direct line api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot Framework doesn't support HTML formatted messages. For complex messages, including support for button actions, form input, and postbacks, use the [Adaptive Cards](http://adaptivecards.io/) spec.

Check out this blog article that provides a walkthrough of Adaptive Cards design and usage in .NET:

- https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/07/Adaptive-Card-Dotnet/

For more information on Adaptive Cards see:

- Adaptive Cards Samples: http://adaptivecards.io/samples/
- Adaptive Cards Visualizer: http://adaptivecards.io/visualizer/
- Bot Framework .NET - Add rich card attachments to messages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments

Comment: Is there a way to do what i want though? In the html, I'm sending an email and making a call through the buttons. But can the same thing be done using Adaptive card buttons ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. WebChat will not let through raw HTML, any more than any other chat client (e.g. Facebook Messenger, Skype, Slack) would.

This [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/244) in GitHub discusses this.